# Save an image in Android browser

Tags: browser

When I save an image from a WebPage in android browser, can you please tell me where does that go? Which directory does that file go?
I tried mounting the phone to my computer, but I can't find that file.

Please help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a file manager such as [ASTRO File Manager](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.metago.astro&hl=en). I'll use my file manager quick to check though.

EDIT: So on my Galaxy S2 the directory is /sdcard/download. /sdcard is the root directory on my phone and not actually an sd card. It's the 2GB of app storage on my phone